# Keep form's state in normal after clicking on help button

Tags: c#, .net

I have a window form with a help button. When user click on this button, a help form will be opened. However, window form' state will be context help with a help cursor. I want keep window form' state in normal state (not context help) whether I click on help button. Please help me. Thanks.

P/S: I use C# .NET 2.0 and WinForms programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `OnHelpRequested` method in form class and set `e.Cancel` to `true`:

```
protected override void OnHelpButtonClicked(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    base.OnHelpButtonClicked(e);
    MessageBox.Show("Help goes here.");
}
```